# TFS:How to merge project from to branch without this project

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I have branches `Branch1` and `Branch-my-newfeature`. On the second branch I created a project `MyProject`, which was absent on the first branch.

How do I merge (or just copy?) this new project from second branch to first branch?

Answer (score 1):

1.In **Source Control Explorer**, select the second branch that you want to merge.

2.Click the File menu, point to Source Control, point to **Branching and Merging**, and then click **Merge**.The **Source Control Merge Wizard** will displayed.

3.In the **Target branch** drop-down list, select the target team project branch  to which you want to merge the source branch(first branch).

4.Select the range of changes that you want to merge into the target branch by selecting either the **All changes up to a specific version** or **Selected changesets option**, and click Next.

5.Click **Next**, and then on the **Perform the merge operation** page, click **Finish**. One or more pending changes are generated.

Comment: In point 3, no options are displayed in the drop-down list, since the target branch for the project does not exists yet.